# Partials template in underscore (just like in handlebars)?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I have a backbone model like this

```
var PeopleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {              
    "people": [
          { "username": "alan", "firstName": "Alan", "lastName": "Johnson", "phone": "1111", "email": "alan@test.com" },
          { "username": "allison", firstName: "Allison", "lastName": "House", "phone": "2222", "email": "allison@test.com" },
          { "username": "ryan", "firstName": "Ryan", "lastName": "Carson", "phone": "3333", "email": "ryan@test.com" },
          { "username": "ed", "firstName": "Edward", "lastName": "Feild", "phone": "4444", "email": "ed@test.com" },
          { "username": "phil", "firstName": "Philip", "lastName": "Doom", "phone": "5555", "email": "phil@test.com" },
          { "username": "gerald", "firstName": "Gerald", "lastName": "Butler", "phone": "6666", "email": "gerald@test.com" }
    ],
    "company": {"name": "Random Corp."},
    "country": "England"
}

});
```

And below are my templates

```
<script id="people-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each people}}
  {{> person}}
{{/each}}
</script>

<script id="person-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <div class="person">
    <h2>{{fullName}} </h2>
    <div class="phone">{{phone}}</div>
   <div class="email"><a href="mailto:{{email}}">{{email}}</a></div>    
 </div>
```

This is how I implemented partial using handlebars.js.

My questions

**1.Do we have similar thing, I mean the partials incase of underscore.js template engine?**

**2.If so how do we implement partial in underscore.js template engine**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no native partial support in Underscore's templates. But, you can put pretty much any JavaScript you want inside `<% ... %>`; in particular, you can call your own functions so you can add something partial-ish without much difficulty. You could have a template like this:

```
<script id="people-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <% _(people).each(function(person) { %>
      <%= partial('person', person) %>
    <% }) %>
</script>
```

and then add a `partial` function to `window`:

```
window.partial = function(which, data) {
    var tmpl = $('#' + which + '-partial').html();
    return _.template(tmpl)(data);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HDuj5/9/

That's not quite as slick and pretty as `{{> ... }}` in Handlebars but Underscore's templates are a very thin wrapper around JavaScript itself and that limits you somewhat. You can use namespaces to avoid putting things directly in `window` or you could use the [`{variable: ...}` option to `_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and a wrapper to set up your standard helpers.

Comment: Thanks for patiently answering my question, your fiddle helped a lot. I completely forgot about using "window" for this case. Thnks again

Comment: Beware that the two-argument version of `_.template()` with data as the second argument has been deprectated as of version 1.7. The approach is still sound, though.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch: Thanks for the reminder. I've actually answered some "why doesn't `_.template(tmpl, data)` work?" questions recently.

Answer (score 13):

Or to avoid using global scope you can mix in global template helpers like so:

```
(function() {
    var originalUnderscoreTemplateFunction = _.template;
    var templateHelpers = {};

    _.mixin({
        addTemplateHelpers : function( newHelpers ) {
            _.extend( templateHelpers, newHelpers );
        },

        template : function(text, data, settings) {
            // replace the built in _.template function with one that supports the addTemplateHelpers
            // function above. Basically the combo of the addTemplateHelpers function and this new
            // template function allows us to mix in global "helpers" to the data objects passed
            // to all our templates when they render. This replacement template function just wraps
            // the original _.template function, so it sould be pretty break-resistent moving forward.

            if( data )
            {
                // if data is supplied, the original _.template function just returns the raw value of the
                // render function (the final rentered html/text). So in this case we just extend
                // the data param with our templateHelpers and return raw value as well.

                _.defaults( data, templateHelpers ); // extend data with our helper functions
                return originalUnderscoreTemplateFunction.apply( this, arguments ); // pass the buck to the original _.template function
            }

            var template = originalUnderscoreTemplateFunction.apply( this, arguments );

            var wrappedTemplate = function( data ) {
                _.defaults( data, templateHelpers );
                return template.apply( this, arguments );
            };

            return wrappedTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call

```
_.addTemplateHelpers( {
    partial : function() {
        return _.template(
            $('#' + which + '-partial').html(),
            data
        );
    }
} );
```

Here is a link to the [underscore mixin](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/underscore-template-helpers) on github.

Comment: Could you possibly do something with _.partial and _.template to achieve this?

Comment: _.partial isn't related to template partials: it fills in arguments in functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is similar to Dave's answer, but perhaps requiring less code:

```
function partialTemplate(origTemplate, partialValues){
    return function(values){
        return origTemplate(_.defaults(values, partialValues));
    };
}
```

Example usage:

```
var t = _.template('<%= val1 %>,<%= val2 %>'); // original template requiring 2 values
var pt = partialTemplate(t, {val1:1}); // partial template with 1 value pre-populated
pt({val2:2}); // returns '1,2'
pt({val2:3}); // returns '1,3'
```